# How to use pub/sub pattern in Event Sourcing & CQRS

Tags: publish-subscribe, cqrs, azure-table-storage, event-sourcing, dddd

I am developing micro-services, I am using Event Sourcing with CQRS pattern, in my case, If a user is deleted/ updated from one service I want it to publish an event and other service to subscribe it and delete the entries regarding that user from its db as well.

I wanted to ask how can I use pub/sub pattern in Event Sourcing, Which Event store can be used for it as currently I have seen some people using Azure Tables  but how can it be used as pub/sub?

Comment: How do you project events to your read model if your events are in Azure Table storage?

Comment: Currently, I am not using any Event Store. I am also looking for such a solution where I can project my events to the read model, which cannot be done through Azure Table Storage. That is why I am asking for a Event Store which can do this automatically

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the EventStore (http://www.geteventstore.com) supports subscriptions and this feature is the best way to build read models. Although projections are not pub-sub. The latter is the messaging pattern.

Answer (score 3):

> Which Event store can be used for it ...?

If you have the luxury of choosing the technology to use, then I would suggest you start out by looking into Greg Young's [Event Store](https://geteventstore.com/)

Yes, that's the same guy that introduced CQRS to the world.

(You may also want to review his talk on [polyglot data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME), which includes discussion of pull vs push based models).

Answer (score 0):

> how can I use pub/sub pattern in Event Sourcing

This use case naturally lays down on eventsourcing and if accurately to realize it, then the question about notifications will disappear by itself.
It is the best of all to realize interaction by means of the common bus. Each microservice realizing your aggregates or projections is connected in the uniform logical bus, and signed on all events, and also can send any events there.

Of course, when if the system is under a heavy load, it is necessary to do some to optimization, for example, to enter name spaces for events and to specify to the broker of the bus what events and to what microservice it is necessary to deliver. Also if some information is private for microservice, then it makes a sense to make private channel in the bus, however it isn't provided by the theory of eventsourcing, exactly the same as validation between aggregates.

Also thanks to the concept of the common bus, you also receive "as a gift" reactivity for clients of system, for example, of browsers. However you shan't subscribe for projections or statuses of aggregates, only for events. If server events aren't equal client, you can enter the intermediate entity on their broadcasting, however it is not responsibility of storage of events any more.

Comment: I suppose you mean "implement" every time you say "realize". Right?